# File permissions on mounted drives and inaccessible folders

Tags: permissions

If I'm logged in as Administrator then why am I not allowed full access to my files on my external hard drives?
I have two ext hard drives that were previously formatted with Mac OSX, now I'm connecting them to my Dell laptop running EOS 6.1.
The file permissions on these drives are messed up, some folders completely inaccessible others readable but can't copy etc.
I also have an SD card running on an ext mp3 player which is formatted by the mp3 player, this too has similar problems.

I'm a noob and so not great at terminal commands but able to follow clear instructions if i could find them. Many other questions about this topic do not appear to provide a solution if I'm already logged in as administrator.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: just came from the other issue concerning USB mounts ... uh ... this is a bit ambiguous ... do you mean that you are logged on as root ... or that you are in the admin group/wheel? they are two different things ... to run as root in the command line ... "sudo su -" will log you in as root for that terminal session ... see if you can then access all of your files that you need ... just copy the files ... if you have a large number of files ... suggest you create a dir for them with proper ownership and access ... copy the fiiles there ... then change ownership of the files with one command

Comment: I think the reason this is ambiguous is because you clearly understand Linux and the use of the Terminal and I don't. I only use the OS with the GUI, I have never worked with Terminal. So as a complete beginner I honestly not even sure how to answer your questions or follow your (to me vague) instructions.

Comment: I have no intention of guessing my way through Terminal commands, especially if there's a risk of causing damage by editing permissions. I would be happy to follow detailed and specific instructions but using the OS regularly with Terminal commands is not what I'm looking for, and being able to browse/edit files on my external hard drives shouldn't really mean having to learn Terminal commands. Perhaps Linux isn't for me, but that's not how it's presented by the Linux-using community. I can't even imagine using WIndows anymore and would prefer to support a good Linux OS.