# Why in the World does Elementary OS make it impossible to access a USB hard drive?

Tags: disk-management, user, bugs

I've been all over the internet on this.  EO will only mount my usb hard drives as root. So all my files are inaccessible. The disk utility is absolutely useless, no menu, no options, no hope. Am I the only person having this problem?

I am not a stupid user, and I've really tried to figure this out.  Am about to give up on EO, Ubuntu, perhaps Debian, and I have used Linux for YEARS without having this horribly disabling problem.

No my disks are not corrupted. Please don't respond with esoteric material, this should be an easy thing to do...unless you want to chase users away screaming in distress.Which as I've indicated, I'm about to do. I'm even considering installing Windows

elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue and have found no answer yet.

See my two questions;
[Permissions  problem](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/29831/file-permissions-on-mounted-drives-and-inaccessible-folders)
[Disk utility](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/29866/disk-utility-for-eos)

I can't even seem to find a disk utility of any kind, can you suggest which one to use? Gnome Disks doesn't seem to exist anymore or at least isn't available for eOS.

Comment: I have been running Ubuntu for a few months now just to see if I prefer it to EOS ... was just about ready to do a new install of EOS 6.1 ... if you can wait for a few days (probably before this weekend is over ... by 7/4/22) I can see if I have this issue ... but my rememberance was that this was not an issue when I last used EOS ...

Comment: but just a few questions for right now... Does it recognize a USB flash drives mounted as non root? Have you tried to mount the drive from the command line into an existing directory that has the correct permissions for the non root user? That is ... create a directory for the mount then either edit /etc/fstab or issue a mount command from the command line

Comment: Thanks George. I've tried it all.

Comment: Having users struggle with the mounting of USB drives formatted to  normal for systems like exfat; it being unusable by users as a default, what are they thinking? That users don't want to use their USB drives? That users want to figure out the maze of USB configuration files that change from version to version? Or perhaps EO wants to cull it's user base of all but there most sophisticated of users?